# java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /server(not local host)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call a rest web api that is hosted in a server.But i am getting 
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /10.***.***.***:45.
It is POST method,passing JSON as parameter.

```
CommonAsyncTask cat=new CommonAsyncTask(MainActivity.this,jsonParam,1);
            cat.delegate = MainActivity.this;
            cat.execute(getResources().getString(R.string.url));
```

I am able open connection but error occurs when i try to getOutputstream on HttpURLConnection object.

Is this the correct way to call a web api written in asp.net from android?
if yes ,please help me fix this error.

```
public class CommonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    JSONObject params;
    // private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    Context mContext;
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
    public static final int POST_TASK = 1;
    public static final int GET_TASK = 2;
    private int taskType;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    InputStream is;
    public CommonAsyncTask(Context mContext, JSONObject params, int taskType) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.params = params;
        this.taskType = taskType;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        /*progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Please wait",
                "Connecting");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);*/

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String result = "";
        try {
            /*
             * Communication with Webservice
             */
            switch (taskType) {

            case POST_TASK:
                Log.d("TAG:","POSTT");
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                Log.d("b4 con","here");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                Log.d("after con.open","here");
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                Log.d("seting post","here");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                Log.d("DOOUTPUT-true","here");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                Log.d("DOinputPUT-true","here");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                Log.d("contenttype-json","here");
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream ());
                Log.d("data outputstream","here");
                wr.writeBytes(params.toString());

                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                Log.d("b4","conn.connect");
                conn.connect();
                 int responsePostCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                 if(responsePostCode>=400){

                        is = conn.getErrorStream();
                    }
                    else{
                        is=conn.getInputStream();
                    }
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                result = response.toString();

                Log.d("LWCP", "Response:  " + result);
                break;
            case GET_TASK:
                /*
                 * String query = String.format("mobile=%s",
                 * URLEncoder.encode(cid, "utf-8"));
                 */
                URL obj = new URL(urls[0]);
                // URL obj = new URL(url[0] + "?mobile=" + cid);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj
                        .openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("Sending'GET'request to:", urls + "");
                Log.d("Response Code : ", responseCode + "");
                Log.d("url-",urls[0]);
                if(responseCode>=400){

                    is = con.getErrorStream();
                }
                else{
                    is=con.getInputStream();
                }
                BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                String inLine;
                StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inLine = inReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseBuffer.append(inLine);
                }
                inReader.close();
                con.connect();
                result = responseBuffer.toString();
                Log.d("LWCP", "Response:  " + result);
                break;
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //progressDialog.dismiss();
        delegate.processFinish(result);
    }   
}
```

sharing my log

```
D/TAG:: POSTT
D/b4 con: here
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/after con.open: here
D/seting post: here
D/DOOUTPUT-true: here
D/DOinputPUT-true: here
D/contenttype-json: here
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /10.142.173.112:45
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
        at com.example.restcall.CommonAsyncTask.doInBackground(CommonAsyncTask.java:78)
        at com.example.restcall.CommonAsyncTask.doInBackground(CommonAsyncTask.java:19)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Is the permission declared in Manifest? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`. Also check that the url can be pinged.

Comment: yes..permision is given in manifest

Comment: did you find the solution of this error? @angh